# Reputation incorrect

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

I just entered a bug report and noticed that the reputation points and badge count  under my photo were not correct, when I viewed the "question". As I'm entering this one on the Ask page, the reputation points and badge count are not correct either.

If I go to my profile in the app, I see the right numbers.  I should say they seem about right.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting confused between Meta and the main site somewhere?

Comment: Cab you post a screenshot?

Comment: Martijn is correct.  I was looking at the rep numbers at the top of my profile.   That appears to be the main SO rep, not the meta site rep.  Somewhat confusing UI

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the reputation you are seeing is correct for the site under which you are asking. You can easily see which site you are asking on by looking at the site logo, or the title in the navigation bar:

[image]

If you tap on the site logo and change the site, you will noticed the reputation in the user card will update accordingly.